# JavaScript auto scale on rotating iPad

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari, viewport, screen-orientation

My page works fine in landscape mode but in portrait mode I have to zoom out a bit and then it fit to screen. so I want to write a JavaScript which scale down or zoom out my page when I rotate in portrait mode

```
if(navigator.platform == 'iPad') {
        window.onorientationchange = function () {
            var orientation = window.orientation;
            // Look at the value of window.orientation:
            if (orientation === 0) {
                alert("iPad is in Portrait mode.");
                 // my code goes here 
                var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
                viewportmeta.content = 'width = 1003,initial-scale = 0.5, maximum-scale = 2.0, minimum-scale=0.7';

            }
            else if (orientation === 90) {
                // iPad is in Landscape mode. The screen is turned to the left.
            }
            else if (orientation === -90) {
                // iPad is in Landscape mode. The screen is turned to the right.
            }
        }

    }
```

it look fine in `scale = 0.5;`

Comment: JS, really? My sites always work in both orientations when using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just i have used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">`
and every this is solved